# How to get X closest terms in future and to past from specified term

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date

How to get 5 closest terms to my specified term? There is list of dates and my specified term.
Ex.

```
My specified term: 10.7.
List:
15.6.
17.6.
24.6.
8.7.
15.7.
22.7.
5.8.
6.8.
```

Expected result:

```
17.6. (23. days back), 
24.6. (16. days back), 
8.7. (2 days back),
15.7. (5 days after my specified term), 
22.7. (12 days after my specified term)
```

Comment: I would suggest to calculate the date diff in days and store the result to an array with the date as key and the result as value, then order the array by value and select the first five entries then with a loop or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to solve this problem：

1. You get the closest term by `abs(diff)`, then you remove the value from the list. You repeat the previous step until you have 5 closest terms.
2. You create a list which contain the index of the value in list and the `abs(diff)`. You sort the list and you can get 5 closest terms by picking the first 5 items from the list.

Hope I helped.